What happens when the energy given to the apparatus of photo electric effect is equal to the work function of the metal?
According to Einstein's photoelectric equation-
$$E= \phi + KE$$
Where $E$ is energy given, $\phi$ is work function and $KE$ is kinetic energy of photoelectron released
So what happens when the energy given is equal to work function? Are electrons released from the surface, cause according to the equation the kinetic energy is zero hence velocity must also be zero.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

If photons with energy equal to work function fall on a metal, then from the equation, you will get that the KE of released electrons is 0. But you have to realize that not all electrons in the metal have equal energy. The work function just gives us the "minimum" energy required to release photoelectrons. Therefore E-$\phi$ is the maximum energy of emitted photoelectrons. But since not all electrons have equal energy, not all electrons are emitted with this "max kinetic energy". There will be some electrons which will come out will less kinetic energy. If the energy of each photon is exactly equal to work function, then maximum kinetic energy is 0. So if a electron gets loose from the surface, it has no speed. Moreover, there will be a positive charge of the plate if the electron gets loose, therefore the electron will go back in the metal plate.
No photoelectric effect will be observed.

Can you please give some more reasoning about the average energy part ?

I have edited the answer. My apologies, I meant maximum kinetic energy.
